# Which $n$ can make $\frac{n!}{n(n-1)...(n-n_0)\; \pi^n}\geq 1$ be true?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My question is:

> For which $n$ respect to $n_0$, the following inequality is true? 
>   $$\frac{n!}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-n_0)\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; ?.$$

Firstly, I checked the different $n$ to find the first number which make the inequality be true. That was $n=9$ and it implied that $n_0=0$ and I continued this method as follows:

If $n=9$ or $n=10$ then $n_0=0$;

If $n=11$ or $n=12$ then $n_0=1$;

If $n=13$ or $n=14$ then $n_0=2$;

If $n=15$ or $n=16$ then $n_0=3$;

If $n=17$ or $n=18$ then $n_0=4$. ...

But I could not find any relation between $n$ and $n_0$ generally. Also which $n$ can make the inequality be true? Thanks.

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot(n-n_0)}=(n-n_0-1)!$$ So you are asking when is $(n-n_0-1)!\geq \pi^n.$

Comment: Letting $m=n-n_0-1$ and using Stirling's approximation, you can search for the smallest $m$ such that $$\left(\frac{m}{\pi e}\right)^m\sqrt{m}> \frac{\pi^{n_0+\frac12}}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Since Stirling is only an approximation, that will give your approximation of the smallest $n=m+n_0+1.$

Comment: @  Thomas Andrews, but I look for the exact value.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a closed form for the exact value, just a way to narrow down the search. But I could be wrong.

Comment: If $n_k$ is the smallest value $n$ when $n_0=k$ then, for all $k,$ $n_{k+1}=n_{k}+1$ or $n_{k+1}=n_k + 2.$ This is because if we have $m_k=n_k-k-1$ then we are seeking $m_k$ so that $$\frac{m_k!}{\pi^{m_k}}\geq \pi^{k+1}.$$ But then, at least when $m_k\geq \pi^2-1,$ you have $$\frac{(m_k+1)!}{\pi^{m_k+1}}=\frac{m_k+1}{\pi} \frac{m_k!}{\pi^{m_k}}\geq \pi \frac{m_k!}{\pi^{m_k}}\geq \pi^{k+2}.$$ So $m_{k+1}=m_k$ or $m_k+1$ and thus $n_{k+1}=m_{k+1}+(k+1)+1=n_k+1$ or $n_k+2.$